# ActiveRecord serialize not working properly with Hash column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to store a Hash in a table column, using ActiveRecord's serialize method but I can't make it work. I'm using Rails 4.2.0 and RailsApi 0.3.1

This is my model:

```
class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :phone_numbers, Hash
end
```

phone_numbers is a text column like it's required.

Then in the console:

```
a = Agreement.new(phone_numbers: {"dario" => "12345"})
a.phone_numbers 
=> "{\"dario\"=>\"12345\"}" #(Note this is a string, not a Hash as I would expect)

a.phone_numbers["dario"]
=> "dario" #(Not "12345" as I would expect)
```

Am I missing soemthing?? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're showing is consistent with the `serialize` call being wrong, either misnamed column, or missing entirely. Eg. https://gist.github.com/smathy/2f4536d3e59b7a52c855

You're showing the right code in your question, so either you didn't copy-paste that correctly, or perhaps it you haven't restarted your rails console since adding/correcting that `serialize` call?

Comment: I'm totally embarrassed, there was a typo in the serialize method. Working 12 hours a day is not a good idea. Thank you anyway!

Comment: There's an even better way to show your gratitude on StackOverflow :)