# Serialize attribute not working in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got exactly this very same question [ActiveRecord serialize not working properly with Hash column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221692/activerecord-serialize-not-working-properly-with-hash-column), but in my case, I've triple checked and I can't find any typos, this is a Copy/Paste:

`app/models/organization.rb`:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  serialize :activities, Array
end
```

`app/views/organizations/_form.html.erb`: Here it works fine, look at the `.include?` method.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= o.label :activities %>
  <% TextsHelper::ACTIVITIES.each_with_index do |activity, i| %>
  <%= label_tag "organization_activities_#{i}" do %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'organization[activities][]', activity, organization.activities.include?(activity), id: "organization_activities_#{i}" %>
  <%= activity %>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

`app/views/organizations/show.html.erb`: Here it *DOES NOT* work, and I really don't know where to keep looking.

```
<h1><%= @organization.name %></h1>

<p>
  <%= t('status.created_at') %>:
  <%= @organization.created_at %><br>
  <%= t('status.updated_at') %>:
  <%= @organization.updated_at %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= Organization.human_attribute_name(:activities) %>:
  <% @organization.activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= activity %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

This is the error in browser:

```
Showing /usr/src/app/app/views/organizations/show.html.erb where line #19 raised:
undefined method `each' for #<String:0x007efe68889ab0>
```

This is via `rails console`:

```
> o = Organization.last
=> #<Organization id: 58 ...>
> o.activities
=> "[\"Fútbol\", \"Fútbol de salón\", \"Baloncesto\", \"Taekwondo\"]"
> o.activities.class
=> String
```

Comment: There was some existing values in DB, I cleaned them up, from all table, and tried to save again. Saved in different format in DB: ```---
- Fútbol
- Fútbol de salón
- Patinaje
- Baloncesto
```

Comment: What is the value of `o.activities_before_type_cast`?